# Apply a diff on multiple files - Ant

Tags: ant, diff

My ant project generates an "output" folder which contains the outputs of multiple runs and I would like to diff them all against files located in an "expected" folder (these lasts have the exact the same name as the ones in the output folder).  I tried that:

```
<apply executable="diff">
    <fileset dir="${output.dir}" />
    <arg value="-u" />
    <srcfile />
    <arg value="${expected.dir}/" />
    <srcfile />
    <redirector>
         <outputmapper type="merge" to="result.out" />
    </redirector>
</apply>
```

But I have two problems:

First I am not allowed to put two `<srclist />` in one `<apply>`, so how can I use two times the name of the current file treated in one `<apply>`?

Second I am not able to get the output of my `<apply>` in one single file. I tried different ways (putting the `output` argument in the `<apply>` tag...) but it always seems to only store the last execution of the apply. How can I append the result of each diff in one single file?

And I don't want to have to install anything else (so no ant-contrib with foreach).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<delete file="result.out" />
<apply executable="diff" force="yes" output="result.out" append="true">
    <fileset dir="${output.dir}" />
    <srcfile />
    <targetfile />
    <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="${expected.dir}/*" />
</apply>
```

Some explanation:

- The [`apply` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) `targetfile` element lets you specify a second arg that is derived from the `srcfile` via the mapper.
- To get the merged output use the `output` attribute and set `append` true.  Note that you may need to delete the output file (i.e. truncate it) otherwise on rerun you'll not get a clean slate.
- I fiddled with the arg list for diff to suit my OS, instead of passing `expected.dir` and the target file as successive elements, the mapper merges them into a single full path to the 'right hand' file for the diff.

Comment: Been reading that Apply Task doc for hours and havn't even noticed the append parameter...facepalm. That's great exactly what I was looking for, I knew it had something to do with targetfile but couldn't find the way to use it.